# Problem after using LuksRemovekey?

Tags: boot, partitioning, encryption, cryptsetup

I have an encrypted partition on /dev/sda5, yesterday I use cryptsetup to remove the encryption using **cryptsetup luksRemovekey /dev/sda5**, but when I restart I have to provide a passphrase for decryption ? (I use the old one but I have this message : No key available with this passphrase)
when I switch to initramfs mode : I have all key slot disabled ? (using **cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda5**)

thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2):

You removed your only key in the LUKS header, *not* the encryption. The passphrase unlocks a master decryption key stored in the header, which in turn decrypts your partition. Cryptsetup asks you for that passphrase, but finds no matching encrypted key in the header since you removed the only keyslot that stores it.

There's no way you will ever decrypt that partition again, unless you had a backup of the header somewhere. Only use luksRemoveKey if you have *another* keyslot left afterwards that you can unlock (or a header backup). When you remove the last key, that master key is lost forever.